# commend in css and html it works only when the page is small

Tags: html, css, hover, cursor, screen

I change the  cursor while hovering - the cursor will change while hovering when the page is small-size not when the page  is large-size - why?
thank you

Comment: without code how we can help you? Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.